# Weird box after finishing an edit review

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reviewing

I finished reviewing an [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/230430) and hit the reject button, and the next page had a weird little box popup. I'm not entirely sure what caused it, though it may be do to my mouse occasionally glitching and double clicking instead of single clicking.
[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you managed to hit 'F12' and check for javascript errors? Was [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/230433) the suggested edit?

Comment: @robotnik no I didn't hit F12. I forgot about that or I would have. Also no that wasn't the edit. I'll see if I can find it and link it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was that edit. I'll keep my eye out to see if I run into it again. I'll check for JavaScript errors if I do. It appears to be one of those boxes saying you can only open an interface once every x seconds that occasionally pops up when I accidentally double click on a button that brings up a menu.

Comment: Has this happened since? Might've been a temporary glitch in the matrix.

Comment: @Robotnik havent been able to repro it, no